# Calling parent directive scope function from child directive which triggers parent watcher

Tags: angularjs, scope, directive

I have 2 directives: `calculatorForm` and `calculatorAttribute`. CalculatorForm is the parent directive, specifically a form which contains input tags which are calculatorAttribute directives.

I want the calculatorAttribute call calculatorForm function that changes a scope variable and trigger a watcher.

Here's my code:

```
angular
    .module('calculator')
        .directive('calculatorForm', ['CalculatorDataModel', 'CalculatorPriceModel',

            function(CalculatorDataModel, CalculatorPriceModel) {

                return {
                    restrict : 'A',
                    replace : true,
                    templateUrl : function(element, attrs) {
                       return attrs.templateUrl;
                    },
                    link : function(scope, element, attrs) {
                        scope.model = CalculatorDataModel;
                        scope.price = CalculatorPriceModel;
                        scope.model.initialize(calculator_data);

                        scope.updateSelectedSpecs = function(attribute_id, prod_attr_val_id) {

                            var selected_specs = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(scope.model.selected_specs));
                            selected_specs[attribute_id] = prod_attr_val_id;
                            scope.model.selected_specs = selected_specs;                         
                        }

                        scope.$watch('model.selected_specs', function(selected_specs, previous_selected_specs) {
                            if (selected_specs != previous_selected_specs) {
                                scope.model.setCalculatorData();
                                scope.price.computePrice();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        ])

        .directive('calculatorAttribute', [
            function() {
                return {
                    restrict : 'A',
                    template : "<input type='radio' name='attr{{attribute_id}}' ng-value='prod_attr_val_id'/>",
                    replace : true,
                    link : function(scope, element, attrs) {
                        scope.attribute_id = attrs.attributeId;
                        scope.prod_attr_val_id = attrs.prodAttrValId;

                        element.on('click', function() {
                            scope.$parent.updateSelectedSpecs(scope.attribute_id, scope.prod_attr_val_id);
                        });

                    }
                }

            }
        ]);
```

My problem is updateSelectedSpecs in the parent is called but watcher has never been triggered when I use element.on click in the child directive.

Please help everyone Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after wrestling with this for a bit, I managed to produce a working version of a slimmed-down example:

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .directive('calculatorForm', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      replace: true,
      transclude: true,
      template: '<div ng-transclude></div>',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.model = {};
        scope.price = {};

        scope.updateSelectedSpecs = function(attribute_id, prod_attr_val_id) {
          scope.$apply(function() {
            console.log('update selected specs');
            var selected_specs = {};
            selected_specs[attribute_id] = prod_attr_val_id;
            scope.model.selected_specs = selected_specs;
          });
        }

        scope.$watch('model.selected_specs', function(selected_specs, previous_selected_specs) {
          console.log('new selected specs', selected_specs, previous_selected_specs);
          if (selected_specs != previous_selected_specs) {
            console.log("and they're different");
          }
        });
      }
    };
  })
  .directive('calculatorAttribute', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      template: "<input type='radio' name='attr{{attribute_id}}' ng-value='prod_attr_val_id'/>",
      replace: true,
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.attribute_id = attrs.attributeId;
        scope.prod_attr_val_id = attrs.prodAttrValId;

        element.on('click', function() {
          scope.$parent.updateSelectedSpecs(scope.attribute_id, scope.prod_attr_val_id);
        });
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<form calculator-form ng-app="myApp">
  <input calculator-attribute attribute-id=1 prod-attr-val-id=1>
</form>
```

Just look at the console to see it getting into the `$watch`. The problem seemed to be the fact that you didn't trigger a `$digest` cycle in your `updateSelectedSpecs` function. Usually a `$timeout`, `$http` call, or `ngClick` or other event would start the `$digest` cycle for you, but in this case you have to start it yourself using `scope.$apply()`.

Comment: AHA GOT it! This is why my watcher worked before when I have $http request inside the updateSelectedSpecs function.

Brilliant @Ionut! scope.$apply did the trick. Thank you so much for wrestling with it!

Comment: I have a follow up question!
If I have multiple instances of calculatorForm which are isolated to each other. updateSelectedSpecs function is triggered to all instances because of scope.$apply. Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: Just set the `calculatorForm` to have an isolate scope by adding the `scope: {}` option in the `calculatorForm` directive function return object. It should work (see: https://jsfiddle.net/souldreamer/evj03uux/ )